# How can I calculate a new date conditionally based on other information?

Tags: if-statement, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a [Google Sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/17qtLpnFTiMoE6blELSTQhtxkWa1hjjzI_PcaY-3cS1Q/edit?resourcekey=null#gid=465252365) which is being populated by a [Google Form](https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSeAyA6zASzOX-o5noqLWKk9wGpeQXf6LWP5_EBXvi1ufH_N0w/viewform).  I am using [Google Apps Script](https://script.google.com/home/projects/1z1hOdOUyUVntZDxlQvWIE3PizyOM5tULbUecaIt7WqOubmmG76LdYe9F/edit) to add some extra functionality. Please feel free to access and modify these as needed in order to help.

Based on answers from the Form, I need to return a new date that factors in the time stamp at form submission.

This is a dumbed down example of what I need to do, but let's think of it like ordering a new car and its color determines how long it is going to take.

| Car | Color |
| --- | --- |
| Toyota | Red |
| Honda | Blue |
| Tesla | Green |

I need to write a conditional IF statement that determines how many weeks it will take to get the car based on the ordered color.

| - | Red | Blue | Green |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Toyota | 1 | 3 | 5 |
| Honda | 2 | 4 | 6 |
| Tesla | 1 | 1 | 1 |

So if you order a Toyota in Red, it will take one week. If you order a Toyota in Green, it will take 5 weeks. If you order a Tesla, it will be really in one week no matter what color. Etc...

I started by writing some language in Sheets to take the Timestamp which is in Column A and add the appropriate amount of time to that:

```
=IFS(AND(B2 = "Toyota",C2 = "Red"),A2 + 7,AND(B2="Toyota",C2="Blue"), A2 + 21,AND(B2="Toyota",C2="Green"), A2 + 35,AND(B2 = "Honda",C2 = "Red"),A2 + 14,AND(B2="Honda",C2="Blue"), A2 + 28,AND(B2="Honda",C2="Green"), A2 + 42,AND(B2 = "Tesla"),A2 + 7)
```

And then I dragged that down the length of the entire column so that it would fill in as submissions came in.

[image]

However when you fill in the Google Form, it will overwrite what's in that entire row, blowing out what I had in that column.

Now I realized that the code needs to be written in Google Apps Script and returned as a value.

What kinds of modifications need to be made to my IFS statement in order to make it compatible with Google Apps Script?

Comment: An easier way to do it would be to get columns A through C in a new sheet (can use QUERY for that) and then use you your IFS formula that is already working. Is this something that you've tried already?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For easier approach, `QUERY` would actually solve your issue without doing script as Broly mentioned in the comment. An approach you can try is to create a new sheet. Then have that sheet contain this formula on `A1`

#### Formula (A1):

`=query('Form Responses 1'!A:C)`

This will copy A:C range from the form responses, and then, copy/paste your formula for column Date Needed on column D.

#### Output:

[image: output]

#### Note:

- Since you only copied A:C, it won't affect column D formula.
- Your A:C in new sheet will update automatically, then the formula you inserted on D will recalculate once they are populated.
- Add `IFNA` on your formula for column D to not show `#N/A` if A:C is still blank.

#### Formula (D2):

`=IFNA(IFS(AND(B2 = "Toyota",C2 = "Red"),A2 + 7,AND(B2="Toyota",C2="Blue"), A2 + 21,AND(B2="Toyota",C2="Green"), A2 + 35,AND(B2 = "Honda",C2 = "Red"),A2 + 14,AND(B2="Honda",C2="Blue"), A2 + 28,AND(B2="Honda",C2="Green"), A2 + 42,AND(B2 = "Tesla"),A2 + 7), "")`